# event.keycode on Javascript

Tags: jquery, dom-events, keyevent

I'm working with a web page containing a form with a textarea element.  I want to restrict the input values to only numbers, using JavaScript.  One method I have found is to check the keyvalues when users are entering data:

```
function checkForEnter() {
if (!((event.keyCode >= 48) || (event.keyCode <= 57))) {                            
//event.stopPropagation(); throw error with IE ver 8
event.cancelBubble = true;
event.returnValue = false;
return false;
                    
  }
}
```

What other method could I use to restrict the values entered?

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454591/allow-only-numeric-value-in-textbox-using-javascript) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks for your help**

this solution works for me

The inputext has attach two events  to the same function(checkForEnter ) , onkeypress and onkeydown

both cases I validate ONLY  numbers

no more bla , bla bla,

```
function checkForEnter() { 
if (event.keyCode == 13) {

var txt = event.srcElement;      

                    }
//that was my problem
//var chCode = ('charCode' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;

//that was my solution
var chCode = event.keyCode; 


                    if (chCode != 8 || chCode != 46) {

//alphanumeric keyboard
                        if (chCode >= 48) {
                            if (chCode <= 57) {
                            }
                            else {
//numeric keyboard
if (chCode > 95 && chCode < 106) {
                                } else {
                                    event.cancelBubble = true;
                                    event.returnValue = false;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
if (chCode == 32) {
   event.cancelBubble = true;
event.returnValue = false;
return false;
}        
}                                      
}
```

ps. I cannot

I can not make multiple comparisons in javascript

: (

for that reason use if .. if .. if

Answer (score 0):

You want [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault), not `event.stopPropagation()`. `preventDefault` stops the default behavior of the key press event (i.e., adding a character into the text field).

Answer (score 0):

Your function is missing an `event` parameter, so invoking methods of an undefined variable naturally results in an error. Try:

```
function checkForEnter(event) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I assume the OP is using `attachEvent` in IE-specific code, which uses a global `event` property. That said, this is still a good suggestion for cross-browser support.